# ¿Por qué puedo escribir html en mi chat?

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

Estoy creando un chat con **nodejs** y **sockets**, entonces en el *frontend* se escucha un *socket* que es el que muestra el mensaje en pantalla:

```
socket.on("new message", function(data) {
    if (data.nick === "") return false;
    $chat.append('<b>' + data.nick + '</b>: '+ data.msg + '<br />');
    $("#chat").scrollTop($("#chat")[0].scrollHeight);
});
```

Me funciona perfectamente, pero el problema es que si escribo código **html** este se visualiza, y yo quisiera que el código **html** no funcionara, solamente algunas etiquetas que yo decida, como la etiqueta `<b>, <i>, <s>` ¿Cómo puedo validar esto? No tengo la menor idea de eso.

Comment: lo podes hacer desde node con https://www.npmjs.com/package/striptags

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto, creo que es lo que necesitas: Puedes usar una expresión regular que filtre las etiquetas de html del data.msg antes de enviar el mensaje:

```
socket.on("new message", function(data) {
  if (data.nick === "") return false;
  let msgFiltrado = data.msg.replace(/(<\/?(?:s(?=>)|i(?=>)|b(?=>))[^>]*>)|<[^>]+>/ig, '$1');
  $chat.append('<b>' + data.nick + '</b>: '+ msgFiltrado + '<br />');
  $("#chat").scrollTop($("#chat")[0].scrollHeight);
});
```

Si quieres permitir mas etiquetas debes agregar un expresión |"nombre_etiqueta"(?=>) por cada etiqueta permitida (solo para etiquetas de una letra), por ejemplo si deseas permitir

puedes agregar /(</?(?:s(?=>)|i(?=>)|b(?=>)|**p(?=>)**)[^>]*>)|<[^>]+>/ig.

Espero te funcione

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de resolver el problema con esta expresión regular que sustituye cualquier etiqueta por un string vacío:

```
data.msg = data.msg.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```